# What is the largest file size that can be opened by Vim? (64-bit)

Tags: vim, 64-bit, text-editor

Apparantly Vim can edit 2GB on 32-bit machines (swap and backup disabled). But for 64-bit machines, what is the limit?

Comment: The link merely says "2147483647 bytes (2 Gbyte) when a long integer is 32 bits.  Much more for 64 bit longs."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vi_diff.html#limits) just states this:

> Maximum file size    2147483647 bytes (2 Gbyte) when a long integer is
>                32 bits.  Much more for 64 bit longs.  Also limited
>                by available disk space for the |swap-file|.

so "much more" will most likely run into your hard drive limitation since it goes to exabytes of alocatable size.

Comment: guess: as 2147483647 is 2 ^ 32 / 2 - 1, then the answer should be 2 ^ 64 / 2 - 1 = 9223372036854775807 bytes or 8 exabytes minus 1 byte. Am i right?

Comment: sindikat was so kind to also supply the link to my really long (pun intended) answer and his calculation should be pretty accurate. In this kind of "memory" size I become lazy and just thay "woah that freaking huge" ;-)

Comment: well... any comfortable editor will choke on those file sizes... but VIM will work for sure. ( not saying VIM isnt comfortable, just most people are not used to work with key shortcuts alone )

Comment: @trusktr: To edit a 32-gigabyte file, you can probably use the 64-bit version of Vim. (The 32-bit version may not work well.) See ["How to edit multi-gigabyte text files?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908575/how-to-edit-multi-gigabyte-text-files-vim-doesnt-work/19795855#19795855) for some additional tips which may help speed things up even more. Why do you want to edit such a big file?

Comment: At the time, I just wanted to reach into the file and edit some info, then import into a wordpress site.