# Make Vim handle medium-sized text files on windows?

Tags: vim

I am trying to open a 200MB text file in gvim on Windows, and it's choking. The vim window opens and just remains blank and unresponsive.  My system has 8GB of RAM and the file opens fine in about 2-5 seconds using notepad.

I found [this SO post on editing very large text files in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908575/how-to-edit-multi-gigabyte-text-files-vim-doesnt-work), and I tried opening the file with plugins turned off:

```
vim -u "NONE" my200MBfile.text
```

But that didn't help.  Is there anything else I can do to make it work?  It seems strange that vim would choke on my machine on what is not really such a large file.

Thanks!

Comment: That command doesn't turn plugins off it just starts without executing your `_vimrc`. Use `vim -u "NONE" --noplugin my200MBfile.text`. Is your file just raw text? Or is it some source file? How long are the lines on average? How many lines?

Comment: @romainl The `--noplugin` doesn't help.  File is raw text and has only one line.  It is a very long array of ints, in json.

Comment: Yes. Vim is known for choking on very long lines. The ceiling is quite high (`:help limits`),  but do you have an idea of the number of characters on that huge ass line? Also did you try disbling swap files?

Comment: well, 200MB of nothing but ints and commas -- not sure what that comes out to in characters.  Seeming more and more clear though that this is a problem that can't be solved.  Disabling swapfile didn't help either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is more likely that vim doesn't like lines that long very much.

Try using a tool like `json_reformat` on the file first...

If you absolutely have to edit the file as-is, try `:syntax off` and possibly `:set nowrap` before you `:edit` the file in question.

Comment: no dice.  i also tried doing both those command after starting with `--noplugin` but it's still choking.  Maybe the answer is just as simple as the first sentence in your post?

Comment: I've tried making a similar file on my machine, and it doesn't matter if it's JSON. When the file length gets between 10 and 20mb, things start crawling, and then they just get absurdly slow after. I recommend reformatting the document with some linebreaks - it will still be valid JSON even if you quickly replace `}` with `}\n` just to temporarily view and edit it. `sed` would be faster, but try powershell like so: `Get-Content json.txt | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\}", "}\`n"} | Set-Content json.txt` -- vim will still be slow on a 200mb file, but it should be usable.

Answer (score 7):

**Most** likely it's the syntax plugin that makes vim halt. I never have any issues with files of Mbs-Gbs. **Unless** I accidentally open them with some - not-so-well-behaved - filetypes.

Press ^C while loading/hanging (interrupting plugins)

```
:syntax off
```

Does the trick. There are other options with *syntax* that makes it easier to work with a file without fully 'synchronized' syntax highlighting

---

I played around with this some more, and I found indeed some of my plugins would make operating on (very) large files very slow. I did this, for fun:

On a large input file (~600Mb):

```
$ wc input.txt.full 
  2674568   2674568 608825278 input.txt.full
```

I launched vim with the following tweaks:

```
vim -u NONE -n +'se nonu nowrap ul=-1 | syn off' input.txt.full
```

Note this

- `-u NONE` prevents execution of initialization (user) scripts and plugins
- `-n` disables the writing of swapfiles (extremely important on slow/small disks)
- `se nonu nowrap ul=-1` disables

  - line numbering
  - line wrapping
  - undo history (setting `undolevels` to a negative value)

  Basically, everything that could take a lot of CPU or memory
- `syn off` to disables syntax highlighing (should only make a difference if syntax highlighting was in effect for the file type)

Now, I wanted to duplicate each line on the line itself (*globally: copy line, join with previous*):

```
:g/^/t.|-j
```

Unfortunately, the file would become too large for available memory (~3Gb)**<sup>1</sup>** so I opted to act on the first 20% (~535,000 lines):

```
:exec "norm 20%"|1,.g/^/t.|-j
```

This works in a "jiffy" and without problems. Manual navigation (jumps, scrolling, mode switching, searching etc.) seems to be responsive.

Commandline Benchmark:

```
$ xxd -c 44 /dev/urandom | head -n 3800000 >  input.txt.full 
$ wc input.txt.full 
  3800000  91820644 627000000 input.txt.full
$ time vim -u NONE -n +'se nonu nowrap ul=-1 | syn off' input.txt.full +'exec "norm 10%"|1,.g/^/t.|-j' +wq

real    0m7.778s
user    0m6.680s
sys 0m0.952s

$ wc input.txt.full 
  3800000 101002757 689940307 input.txt.full
```

(Note that `689940307 ÷ 627000000 = 110.03 %`, so that is exactly right).

This ***isn't slow*** in my book. For comparison, the `wc` invocation *itself* ***takes the same amount of time*** (7.7s).

---

**<sup>1</sup>** All test performed on `tmpfs` to avoid cache differences.

Comment: Did some indepth testing and came up with a list of hints, and a convincing(?) benchmark

Comment: sehe, were your test files just 1 single line like mine?  this is certainly the most impressive answer, and i will upvote it, but it seems @DanFitch has the answer most appropriate to my situation.

Comment: @Jonah I didn't focus on the long lines, because that seemed to be an issue easily addressed. I provided this answer because I found that, contrary to my expectations, I had to do some tweaks to work smoothly with large files _regardless_ of line length. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Although Vim doesn't have a problem opening files of that size (or bigger), it is mentioned that it has a problem of opening a file with, as is your case, only one line (of that size).

You could try various workarounds, but I would suggest going with the "right tool for the right job" approach, and try [EmEditor](http://www.emeditor.com/), a text editor made specifically for editing large files (amongst other things).

Note that this is not Vim bashing, but Vim is an editor for editing source code mostly. An excellent one at that, but like every other tool it has its limitations.