# How to edit large text files

Tags: vim, gedit

I am trying to edit the human reference genome, which is just a text file that is about 5Gb. The problem is that when I try to open it in vim or gedit in order to make changes, my system freezes. Is there a way to make changes that is lower on memory/CPU requirements?

Comment: some helpful hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908575/how-to-edit-multi-gigabyte-text-files-vim-doesnt-work

Comment: A 5GB file will take 5GB of memory no matter what. If you know beforehand what you need to edit you will almost certainly get better results with tools like sed.

Comment: @romaini Thanks actually this works wonderfully. I'm just using `sed -i 's/stringa/stringb/g' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I was able to get the following to work nicely without taking up too much cpu/memory:

`sed -i 's/stringa/stringb/g' file.txt`