# Edit a large JSON file

Tags: json, large-files

## How can I edit a large JSON manually?

I have a large JSON file, about 100 MB. I'd like to manually inspect some attributes, and then add more attributes to some of the objects.

I'd start off by looking at a subset of the file. Say, the 1st 100 objects. I'd gradually scale up to looking then at maybe 250, then a thousand, etc.

Can someone suggest a language or software (I'm running Windows) that excels at this task?

## Some previous suggestion that aren't working or can't work.

- Sublime - Could never load the file. Loading bar forever. Had to kill.
- NotePad++ - Could never load. Froze. Had to kill.
- Anything online - The data is confidential.

## More Python and Jupyter information.

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(data.items()):
        print(i, k, v)
        if i == 2:
            break
```

Causes an error. I think it has to do with Jupyter, but I'm not sure.

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

That makes me wonder if going about it this way is just dumb.

## Possible Solutions

- [Build a custom app using TKinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301309/2669353)
- [Just don't use a Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301473/2669353)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write a simple GUI program. use  TKinter, to create a window and a text area inside it to show the json, a text box where you will input, how many objects you want to see, and a button named `Next` or something to see next and one more button to save.The following will be the functionalities for each of the items.

First you will be reading complete json in python and making it a dict.

**Next Button -**  This will keep iterating based on the value in the TextBox. you could write a custom generator, where it will be yielding based on the number of values required.

**Save Button-**: This will keep saving the current json into a new json or if you could, you can try to write a function to update the current json directly.

**Text Area -** you should take the dictionary and convert to json and show the output from the Next Button's generator.

Comment: Looking into this. If you have some quick example code I can try out, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux (or have an opportunity to transfer the file to *nix) you might wish to check out for number of lines within a file via

```
wc -l myfile.json
```

Let's say, for the purpose of simplicity, that your file has 2530000 lines and you wish to split it into 100k lines each, you can utilize any of the commands available at your distro to split the file further into desired chunks and then to edit them, one by one.

If you are comfortable with going the "linux way", check out some of the hints given on other topics, i.e.
[edit multi-GB file when vi editor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908575/how-to-edit-multi-gigabyte-text-files-vim-doesnt-work)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Well, you'd need to properly "merge" the edited json file chunks in the end, in order to achieve desired changes. If you ask this because of supposed issues due to unpredictable (or hardware) issues occurring in the mean time while you edit and try to merge a file in the end, if integrity is of utmost importance to you, you might wish to involve database server for it. I.e. to create a table in your local mysql server to store the data, then source (or load data infile) the data into that table and alter it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The only *viewer* I have used that works on large files (I had up to 250MB size files) is [Dadroit](https://dadroit.com/). It is fast to view and comes with search.

Now, to edit, I use vi. I search for the location and make local edits. Vim or another simpler editor should work on Windows. Have you tried vscode? 100MB shouldn't be too large for it.

The other awesome terminal tool for viewing and editing data is [Visidata](https://www.visidata.org/). I have had mixed luck with it working on json files.

Answer (score -1):

Not the best answer, but the problem with reading the JSON seems limited to Jupyter Notebooks (or even the limitations of my laptop).

Working in Spyder or running from the command line circumvents the Jupyter error mentioned in the original question.

It'd be great if someone knew how to tweak Jupyter to avoid this problem (sorry, I'm not sure how yet).

Answer (score -3):

for editor,try notepad++
for language, try Python
since you haven't give your data structure, I can't give more answer.

Comment: Notepad++ freezes when I attempt to open it.

The attributes in the JSON aren't well structured. They vary from object to object. But it's still just a JSON.

Comment: how about post your data structures with sample data?

Comment: It's all confidential data. I can't post any contents of the JSON. I'm also having a hard time grasping the structure of the objects because 1.) they're not all the same and 2.) I haven't yet found out a good way to view it.